# Write aligned environment with mathematical symbols

Tags: equations

I try to write this text many times and I find error `missing $`. Can you help me to write this, please:

```
C & = n L \nonumber \\
     & = n 2 R \sin(\phi/n) \nonumber \\ \intertext{As :} \nonumber \\
   \phi & = 2\pi/n \nonumber \\ \intertext{Thus :} \nonumber \\
   C & = 2 n R \sin(\pi/n) \\ \intertext{If n\mapsto\infty (It's mean a polygon with infinite sides) we find :} \nonumber \\
   C_{\infty} & = 2R \lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(\phi/n) \nonumber \\ \intertext{Thus :} \nonumber \\
   C_{\infty} & = 2\pi R \nonumber
```

Comment: Well I suppose the reason for the error is you have maths symbols in your `\intertext`, e.g. `\intertext{If n\mapsto\infty ...}` `\mapsto\infty` needs to be in math mode too, so you would want something like `\intertext{If $n\mapsto\infty$ ...}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use math mode for math inside `\intertext`. Such lines don't need neither `\nonumber` nor `\\`.

Better to use `\shortintertext` for the short lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
         C & = n L \nonumber \\
           & = n 2 R \sin(\phi/n) \nonumber \\
\shortintertext{As:}
      \phi & = 2\pi/n \nonumber \\
\shortintertext{Thus:}
         C & = 2 n R \sin(\pi/n) \\
\intertext{If $n\to\infty$ (meaning a polygon with infinite sides) we find:}
C_{\infty} & = 2R \lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(\phi/n) \nonumber \\
\shortintertext{Thus:}
C_{\infty} & = 2\pi R \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The computation is wrong and probably it should be `\sin{\phi/2)` in the second line. The `\phi` in the limit should be `\pi`.

On the other hand, there is no need to align everything and something should be inline rather than displayed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  C & = n L\\
    & = n\, 2 R \sin(\phi/2)
\end{align*}
As $\phi = 2\pi/n$, we have
\begin{equation}
  C = 2 n R \sin(\pi/n)
\end{equation}
If $n\to\infty$ (meaning a polygon with infinitely many sides) we find
\begin{equation*}
C_{\infty} = 2R \lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(\pi/n)
\end{equation*}
and therefore
\begin{equation*}
C_{\infty} = 2\pi R
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aside: this does *not* prove that the length of the circumference is 2 pi R.

Comment: since the package `mathtools` load `amsmath` it is sufficient load only  the `mathtools` package :-)

Comment: @egreg Always aesthetically and formally stupendous your answers.